# Cannot resolve bean mongoDbFactory

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

IDE cannot recognize bean although declared:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Application context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config/>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

    <!-- Connection to MongoDB server -->
    <mongo:db-factory host="localhost" port="27017" dbname="test" />
    <!-- MongoDB Template -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    </bean>


    <mongo:repositories base-package="mongodb"/>

</beans>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Which IDE are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this using below dependency. Not sure if this API is present in 1.4 version but is definitely there in the version below

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```